# Nifi-Registry - integration with git

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I'm using Apache NiFi-Registry and wanted to integrate it with git.
So, I have a registry docker container with a volume to the directory in the host that the git rep is there. I cloned the rep with https and using unsecured nifi-registry instance in the container.
The providers.xml file looks like this:

```
  <flowPersistenceProvider>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.registry.provider.flow.git.GitFlowPersistenceProvider</class>
    <property name="Flow Storage Directory">rep</property>
    <property name="Remote To Push">origin</property>
    <property name="Remote Access User">myuser</property>
    <property name="Remote Access Password">mypass</property>
  </flowPersistenceProvider>
```

The commits are working fine but it doesn't push:

> ERROR [GitFlowMetaData Push thread] o.a.n.r.p.flow.git.GitFlowMetaData
> Failed to push commits to origin due to
> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
> https://myuser@xxx/path/to/rep.git:
> Secure connection to
> https://myuser@xxx/path/to/rep.git
> could not be established because of SSL problems
> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
> https://myuser@xxx/path/to/rep.git:
> Secure connection to
> https://myuser@xxx/path/to/rep.git
> could not be established because of SSL problems

I already ran this command in my rep:

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: are you able to push manually from that rep?

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde - Yes. I pushed from the host without any problem